# How to test then function of Promise.all with spyOn

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm a newbie to coding, so please ask if more information is necessary.

I want to test a then-block inside a Promise.all with spyOn, but the function get never called.

```
public foo(): void {
    const names = this.getNames();

    Promise.all(
      names.map(name =>
        this.nameService.doSomething( //some params )
      )
    )
      .then(result => this.controller.ok(names))
      .catch(error => {
        //do something
      });
  }
```

This is the test

```
it('should call controller.ok when name is set', () => {
    spyOn(nameService, 'doSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
    spyOn(controller, 'ok');

    service.foo();

  expect(nameService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      //some params
    });
  expect(controller.ok).toHaveBeenCalled(); //fails because never called
  });
```

I've debugged the code and the doSomething get called even with the right params, the code also reaches the then-block.
But the test says, it never gets called, so somewhere in there the code breaks and I don't know why?

The catch-block is not called.

Answer (score 2):

Promises representing the eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation. Within your test, when checking if `controller.ok` has been called, the `Promise` returned by `Promise.all` of method `foo` was not resolved yet. Therefore you need some sort of synchronization.

One possible solution could look as follows.

```
it('should call controller.ok when name is set', () => {
    const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
    spyOn(nameService, 'doSomething').and.callFake(n => {
        const promise = Promise.resolve();
        promises.push(promise);
        return promise;
    });
    spyOn(controller, 'ok');

    service.foo();

    Promise.all(promises)
         .then(r => expect(controller.ok).toHaveBeenCalled());
});
```

The same can be achieved by using `fakeAsync` and `tick` from `@angular/core/testing`.

```
it('should call controller.ok when name is set', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(nameService, 'doSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
    spyOn(controller, 'ok');

    service.foo();
    tick();

    expect(controller.ok).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the test works with your suggestion :) this helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad I was able to help you, would you mind accepting the answer as the correct one?